# How to write the MySQL DATE_ADD() in "generic" SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I am writing my queries in 'standard' / 'generic' SQL so that it runs on any database (MySQL, Postgre etc).

I'd like to use `DATE_ADD()` of MySQL. In Postgre, it would be done with something like  `'2001-01-01'::timestamp + '1 year'::interval;`.

Is there a more 'general' way of writing it so that it runs on both MySQL and Postgre (or others) ?

Comment: Trying to write standard SQL is usually a mistake. Take a look at the databases available, see which features you need, then be brave and just choose a database that meets your needs and code against that. Use the features that database has effectively. "Generic SQL" typically means slow, unmaintainable SQL that only works on the two databases you tested it on.

Comment: To add to Mark's comment, if you need to support different database vendors - either look to an ORM (trading coding simplicity for performance) or use SQL customized to each database vendor (better performance, more work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are not SQL standard functions for date addition.

Depending on how you're building your app (using a database abstraction layer and/or interface layer), you could probably handle it in a generic way there, and still have the database doing the math, not your code.

Comment: The operations `timestamp + interval`, `timestamp - interval`, `timestamp - timestamp`  and `date - date` are specified in the SQL standard

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you don't need DATE_ADD, it has almost the same syntax as PostgreSQL:

MySQL: `SELECT CAST('2001-01-01' AS date) + INTERVAL 1 year;`

PostgreSQL: `SELECT CAST('2001-01-01' AS date) + INTERVAL '1 year';`